# How to typedef for call CreateThread, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE, lpStartAddress, ThreadProc

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, winmain

WARNING: THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CODE.

I need to define this typedef and this definitions to get the code to compile well.

I have the following code and I need to know what should be in **__WHAT_HERE1 and _**_WHAT_HERE2:

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <winbase.h>

_ifdef _WIN32_
    typedef ____WHAT_HERE1 THREAD_TYPE;
_endif

_ifdef _LINUX_
    typedef void (*THREAD_TYPE);
_endif

    THREAD_TYPE thread_function( void * )
    {

    }

    class ThreadInfo {
    public:
_ifdef _WIN32_
        ____WHAT_HERE2 func;
        LPVOID args;
_endif
_ifdef _LINUX_
    void *(*func) (void*);
    void *args;
_endif
    }

    ThreadInfo *infoThread;


    CreateThread(
        NULL, 
        0, 
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) infoThread->func, 
        infoThread->args, 
        0, 
        NULL
    );
```

Comment: Have you searched for e.g. [`LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`](https://www.google.com/search?q=msdn+LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)?

Answer (score 3):

You can deduce the type from the code you pasted:

1. According to the [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation, the third argument is of type `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`. You're apparently aware of this already, as you cast `infoThread->func` to that.
2. Hence, `____WHAT_HERE2` (the type of `infoThread->func`) should be `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`.
3. Since you will probably assign the address of the `thread_function` function to `infoThread->func`, the return value of the function (denoted by `____WHAT_HERE1` in your code sketch) should be the return type as indicated by `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`. Checking the [`LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964928.aspx) documentation shows that this is `DWORD`.

However, this will not be sufficient since on Windows, a thread procedure uses the `__stdcall` calling convention. You need to take that into account when defining your `thread_function`.